# MVC 3 assembly conflict How to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, reference, runtime-error, .net-assembly

Every time I download some open source or paid MVC3 app I get some assembly conflicts, ie: missing assemblies, wrong versions etc. So I figure I should ask a more general question:

In a typical project you have a folder called References and all assemblies seem to be in that folder, with their version numbers and Copy To Local options etc.

However out of the 10-20 references in that folder I often find just a few in the web.config.

I the latest case of this annoying mixup I have in web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

I get an error that project trying to load System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0 - it's not found.

In the References folder the System.Web.Helpers referenced is version 2.0.0 and it's not possible to change this version number as it's greyed out. Changing to Specific Version doesn't change anything.

**Question:**

Why are there the 4 references in Web.config? Why not just the references folder?

Why do i often find *a partial number of assembly tags* in web.config instead of none or alternatively  all the references seen under the References project folder?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to re-install MVC3? Those references in the Web.config are ok, as they should be...

Here is my Web.config, in that part....

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```